# unity engine bundle in .obb expansion pack

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am using Unity engine.
I want to make my app as .apk + .obb which the Unity does provide an option for.
I also want to setup asset bundles which can be downloaded for game updates.

Here are my questions

1) can I pack asset bundles only into .obb. Are asset bundles packable into a .obb file ?
2) I have a prefab in .obb file but I want to use a newer version in the asset bundle which I will download. How to know the version ? 
3) Basically we use LoadFromCacheOrDownload to load the bundle. If a bundle is part of .obb can LoadFromCacheOrDownload() load that bundle from .obb as cache ?

Answer (score 1):

1) & 3) You cannot treat your .obb as separate bundle from your application. It is stated in [Unity Documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-OBBsupport.html) :

> The contents of the .obb are never used manually. Always treat the .apk+.obb as a unique bundle, the same way you would treat a single big .apk.

2) You can determine Version of .obb file in .obb file name, [OBB Downloder Plugin](http://u3d.as/content/unity-technologies/google-play-obb-downloader/2Qq) will handle the download process

> main.[A_VERSION_NUMBER].[YOUR_GAME_BUNDLE_ID].obb